# Roll-Up Summary field is not calculating

Tags: roll-up-summary, rolluphelper

We have a roll-up summary field on the opportunity to Summarize opportunity line items list price after the discount and it's not calculating automatically until unless we edit and save all line items(Dummy Update).

Is there any worked around for this issue ?

Comment: Using roll-up helper/declarative roll-up summary?

Comment: it's a declarative roll-up summary field.

Comment: I am assuming that you are talking about existing records? How long has it been since you added it. It could still be calculating for all records

Comment: for existing records edit it and save it then you may get  rollup result.

Comment: @Eric ..We waited for hours to get calculated but it never calculates on its own , We have to manually edit all line items and save it recalculate .

Comment: Is there a little hour glass figure displayed on the page next to that field?

Answer (score 1):

Are any icons displayed near the field such as an hourglass? According to the [Salesforce documentation](http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000041377):

> If you have created a roll-up summary field and it continues to display the spinning hour-glass icon, you may have advanced currency management enabled and be summarizing a currency field on the opportunity object.
>
> ...
>
> If you had set up any currency-related roll-up summary fields on the opportunity object, these will be disabled and their values will no longer be calculated.